# how can i store 64 bit string in integer column?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have one column wherein I am converting domain_name to 64 bit bigint string.

it successfully converting it.

```
CONV(SUBSTRING(CAST(SHA(TRIM("#arguments.domain_name#")) AS CHAR), 1, 16), 16, 10),
```

I want use this converted string in another table and trying to store it as Integer. when i have tried casting it like this

```
CAST(arguments.siteid AS INT(11) AS INTEGER)
```

got error; You have an SQL syntax error.

I have tried to store it in another way like

```
<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.siteid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
```

it is storing something else like `2147483647` though the siteid is `14177909183865716377`.
can anyone help me how to cast it ?

Comment: I think you'll find `2147483647` is the biggest value you can put in an integer. You'll need to use an unsigned `BIGINT`, I think: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: so it sounds like there is no way to cast it into integer ? but anyways thanks a lot I just use `unsigned bigint` and it works.

Comment: No, not possible to put something too big into a container that's too small. It's the same in IT as it is in physics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading my observation in a comment to an answer, given it was borne out to be the case:

> I think you'll find 2147483647 is the biggest value you can put in an
>   integer. You'll need to use an unsigned BIGINT, I think, based on the docs: "[MySQL 5.0
>   Reference Manual :: 11 Data Types :: Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)".